# "->" or "=>" in PHP

Tags: php, web

I find myself using `->` and `=>` in different scenarios while programming in PHP and I would like to know the difference between these two operators.

Two examples would be:

```
Cache::section('group')->put('key', $value);
```

and

```
return Response::json(array('key' => 'value'));
```

Just for reference I'll state I use Laravel as my framework.

Comment: `->` is for calling object property and `=>` is used for assigning values to a key in associative arrays

Comment: The question is about `php` not `laravel`.

Comment: I've edited the question acordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

`=>` adds `key => value` into an array. `->` calls method on object or gets object property.